# Does the embedding of the Kleisli category of a monad into its Eilenberg-Moore category have a right adjoint?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, monads

Let $(T,m,e)$ be a monad on a category $\mathcal{A}$. There is a full and faithful functor $J_T$ from the Kleisli category $\operatorname{Kl}(T)$ of $T$ to its Eilenberg-Moore category $\operatorname{EM}(T)$ defined by $J_T(X)=(T(X),m_X)$ on objects and sending a morphism $s:X \rightarrow Y$ in $\operatorname{Kl}(T)$ (i.e. $s$ goes from $X$ to $T(Y)$ as a morphism in $\mathcal{A}$) to $m_Y\circ T(s)$ (here the composition is in $\mathcal{A}$).

My question is whether such functor $J_T$ has a right adjoint.

Comment: It feels like this should only be true when the inclusion is an equivalence (like for vector spaces for instance).

Comment: @Captain Lama - Yes. In the case you mention the right adjoint is just the normal right adjoint of the "canonical functor" that goes from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\operatorname{KL}(T)$. But what happens in general?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since every algebra is a coequalizer of free algebras, if $J$ is a left adjoint and the Eilenberg-Moore category is cocomplete, then $J$ is an equivalence. This follows from the fact that coreflective subcategories of cocomplete categories are closed under colimits. It is very common for the Eilenberg-Moore category to be cocomplete-for instance it suffices that $\mathcal A$ be locally presentable and $T$ preserve sufficiently filtered colimits, or that every epimorphism splits in $\mathcal A$, such as for sets.

**EDIT:** As Arnaud points out, cocompleteness is not necessary here-the canonical coequalizer in the EM category will be reflected back into the Kleisli category whether or not other colimits exist. So it’s necessary and sufficient that $J$ be an equivalence.

Comment: Why do you even need the Eilenberg-Moore category to be cocomplete ? A fully faithful left adjoint creates colimits that exist in its codomain, and here we know that the coequalizer exists in the Eilenberg-Moore category.

Comment: @Arnaud D. Of course, thanks.